# Use jQuery to replace a string

Tags: jquery, regex

There is one condition that I am stuck with:

Replace the particular sequence, e.g. `MA`, in a string with blank only if `MA` does not precede or succeed with an alphabet.

For example:

Input string:

```
string abc= "This is a MAin method with MA .Use your MA and MAt it "
```

Output string:

```
string result = "This is a MAin method with .Use your and MAt it "
```

Note: I have written `MA` with capital letters for clarification. We have to do it using jQuery.

Comment: Hmm How about `.val().replace(" MA ", " ")`

Comment: We know now what you want, but don't know your question. "Write it for me"?

Comment: @p0rter:It's not  homework .Just trying my hands on Jquey and stuck in this situation.
Thanks,

Comment: FTR all the downvotes are because you did not even try doing it yourself but rather prefer the easier way of "give me working code".

Comment: Smells like the homework is wrong.  Did the instructions say REGEX?

Comment: @L.B :Replace a particular character sequence (e.g.:USD) with blank, only when USD does not does not precede or succeed with an alphabet.
e.g.
string abc= "This is a USDin method with USD.Use your USD and USDt it "
string result = "This is a USDin method with .Use your and USDt it "

Comment: Give the guy a break, he might not know about RegExp and may be new to Javascript.  I thought the purpose of this site was to help people.

Comment: @mVChr to help people that at least show some effort to do it.

Comment: @mVChr :Thanks >
Actually I am new to client side coding.
This is the reason I am looking for help.

Comment: 2 minutes of googling to find the answer to your "question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a RegEx such as `MA\s([^a-zA-Z]+)`

And then in javascript (no jquery needed) do something like this:

```
var abc = 'This is a MAin method with MA .Use your MA and MAt it ';
var result = abc.replace(/MA\s*([^a-zA-Z]+)/g, '$1')
console.log('We want: This is a MAin method with .Use your and MAt it');
console.log('We got:  ' + result);
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/gjFCa/

You'll get the following output:

```
We want: This is a MAin method with .Use your and MAt it
We got:  This is a MAin method with .Use your  and MAt it
```

So with a space too much, but you should be able to replace that with a simple `result = result.replace('  ', ' ');`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery, just a simple Javascript RegExp:

```
var input = "This is a MAin method with MA .Use your MA and MAt it ",    
    output = input.replace(/([^A-Za-z])(MA)([^A-Za-z])/g, '$1$3');
```

The `[^A-Za-z]` in the RegExp means "not an alphabet character" like you phrased in your question.  If you want to include numbers as well you can add `0-9`.  If you don't care whether `MA` is upper or lowercase end your RegExp with `/ig` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "This is a MAin method with MA .Use your MA and MAt it ";

output = input.replace('MA ', '');
```